# Pandas:reshape table and plotting different times series in one plot

Tags: python, pandas, plot, time-series

Im rocky to pandas or python for that case and I'm working with a 311 dataset. The output Im trying to get is a plot with 5 time series, one for each NYC borough. Where each point in the plot represents the total number of complaints for each "created date" in that period of time. My data is as follow:
                                        Agency Name           Complaint Type  \      Borough
Created Date
2013-08-30 23:58:55  New York City Police Department          Noise - Vehicle       BROOKLYN
2013-08-30 23:58:28  New York City Police Department          Noise - Vehicle       QUEENS
2013-08-30 23:57:46  New York City Police Department  Noise - Street/Sidewalk       MANHATTAN
2013-08-30 23:55:07  New York City Police Department  Noise - Street/Sidewalk       QUEENS
2013-08-30 23:55:06  New York City Police Department       Noise - Commercial       MANHATTAN

X= created date, Y= Total No.of complaints.

My code so far (overlooking at some stackoverflow queries and libraries):

```
df=pd.read_csv(sys.argv[1], parse_dates=True)
df.set_index("Created Date", inplace=True)
df2=df[["Borough","Complaint Type"]]
df3=df2.groupby("Complaint Type").count()
df3.plot()
plt.show()
```

!https://i.stack.imgur.com/JBP5q.jpg

I did some changes but still it doesn't work:

```
df=pd.read_csv(sys.argv[1], parse_dates=True)
df.set_index("Created Date", inplace=True)
df2=df[["Borough","Complaint Type"]]
df3=df[df2.groupby("Complaint Type")].count()
df3.plot()
```

I really appreciated any help. :)

Comment: `df3=df2.groupby("Complaint Type").count().reset_index()` ??

Comment: Hi! Thank you,but it's not working. The index is not the "Created Date". I also tried this: df3=df2.groupby("Complaint Type").count().reset_index("Created Date).